# How can I implement a Kotlin suspend method in a Java class?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a `Kotlin` interface

```kotlin
interface MyKotlinInterface {
    suspend fun mySuspendableMethod(): List<String>
}
```

then I created a `Java` class, and implemented `MyKotlinInterface`

```java
public class MyJavaImpl implements MyKotlinInterface {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object mySuspendableMethod(@NotNull Continuation<? super List<? extends String>> completion) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

the IDE shows no error, but when I compile am getting below error

> error: MyJavaImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract
> method mySuspendableMethod(Continuation<? super List>) in
> MyKotlinInterface public class MyJavaImpl implements MyKotlinInterface
> {

So my questions are

1. Is it possible to do this?
2. If it's not possible, why IDE doesn't show any error? and why IDE converts the `suspend` method to `Continuation` param.

[image]

3. If it's possible, why am I getting this error? and How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I've changed

```kotlin
@NotNull Continuation<? super List<? extends String>> completion
```

to

```kotlin
@NotNull Continuation completion
```

and the compile-time error has gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best material on how `suspend` methods work in Kotlin behind the scenes is this file in the Kotlin repo:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/3709/files

As you've correctly noted, `suspend` keyword informs Kotlin compiler to transform the function into a statemachine, or, in maybe a bit more familiar terms, into a chain of callbacks.

To pass information between callbacks we need something to hold the result of the previous computation. This is the `Continuation` you see. The generic type, in your case List, is what the last call in the chain of callbacks should produce.

Since generics in JVM are a compile-time concept, by erasing them altogether you circumvented the issue, but not really solved it.

**Why IDE doesn't alert regarding compilation issues?**
AFAIK IntelliJ IDEA uses its own version of compiler in order to recognize the issues as they occur. This compiler is optimised for performance, and doesn't handle some edge cases.

**How to solve the issue**
Put a type on your interface:

```kotlin
interface MyKotlinInterface<T> {
    suspend fun mySuspendableMethod(): List<T>
}
```

Your Java class will have to change slightly:

```java
public class MyJavaImpl<T> implements MyKotlinInterface<T> {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object mySuspendableMethod(@NotNull Continuation<? super List<? extends T>> $completion) {
        return List.of("A", "B");
    }
}
```

But it will run and compile fine:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val impl = MyJavaImpl<String>()

    println(impl.mySuspendableMethod())
}
```